# Tivix - angular-django-registration-auth with Ionic?

Tags: python, angularjs, django, ionic-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to create a user registration with Ionic and I installed Tivix's django backend, and the angular-django in eh front end. The thing is, I'm trying to incorporate it into Ionic.

[Here's my app structure in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUK7C.jpg)

[in my index.hml i have included the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMbEg.jpg)

I'm just having trouble understanding since how would I include the app **"angularDjangoRegistrationAuthApp"** into my index.html?

[I tried doing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGmek.jpg) in my index.html file. but when I click Sign Up button nothing happens. If anyone has ever worked with Tivix's module before and can poit me in the right direction, it would help allot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. [Ionic Creator is your friend.](https://creator.ionic.io/)